# Check if a simple product with same config options exist in a configurable product's associated products

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, import, ebay

I am importing products from my eBay store. To get products, I have created a script which creates products from eBay response data.

When I run the script for the first time, It creates all the products in my magento store. But **for some of the products, there is no sku defined in eBay response data, so I have generated a random sku for those products**.

My problem is when I try to run the script again to update the products, it does not get the products for which I have generated random sku value.

Is there any way I can compare config option values with all the available associated products to get right product to update.

Comment: If you are developing module then it's diff case but if you are looking to import your products only then try this: http://m2epro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// Assume configurable product id is 135
$parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(135); 
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getUsedProducts(null,$parentProduct);   

foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    var_dump($child->getData()); break;
 /* You can get the required data against each child product 
     and check with the parent product's options. */
}
```

Comment: Can I know the reason for down voting?